# How can I efficiently parse formatted text from a file in Qt?

Tags: parsing, qt5

I would like to get efficient way of working with Strings in Qt. Since I am new in Qt environment.

So What I am doing:

I am loading a text file, and getting each lines. 
Each line has text with comma separated. 
Line schema:

```
 Fname{limit:list:option}, Lname{limit:list:option} ... etc.
```

Example:

```
 John{0:0:0}, Lname{0:0:0}
```

Notes:limit can be 1 or 0 and the same as others.

So I would like to get Fname and get limit,list,option values from {}.

I am thinking to write a code with find { and takes what is inside, by reading symbol by symbol.

What is the efficient way to parse that?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

The following snippet will give you Fname and limit,list,option from the first set of brackets.  It could be easily updated if you are interested in the Lname set as well.

```
QFile file("input.txt");
if (!file.open(QIODevice::ReadOnly | QIODevice::Text))
    qDebug() << "Failed to open input file.";

QRegularExpression re("(?<name>\\w+)\\{(?<limit>[0-1]):(?<list>[0-1]):(?<option>[0-1])}");

while (!file.atEnd())
{
    QString line = file.readLine();
    QRegularExpressionMatch match = re.match(line);

    QString name = match.captured("name");
    int limit = match.captured("limit").toInt();
    int list = match.captured("list").toInt();
    int option = match.captured("option").toInt();

    // Do something with values ...
}
```